# Merge Polyline and lines to Polygonize

Tags: qgis, line, polygon-creation, polygonize

I have 3 different strings: (Route) is a polyline coming out of a shapefile in which I removed all other routes, the other two (River and Trail) are imported KML's, which I created in google earth.

I am interested in the boundary these three strings form, and would like to make a polygon out of the shape (By connecting the end nodes of "River" and "Trail", this can be done randomly as I will later cut the created polygon with bordering polygons).

I know how to do the second part (connecting end nodes with "Node Tool" and polygonize with "Polygonize algorithm"), but how can I merge all three lines so that QGIS will see them as 1 Linestring?

[image: RiverTrailRoute]

Finally I would like to make such a Shape (Which I tried and failed since QGIS sees them as separate linestrings I believe).

[image: Firstversion]

Answer (score 3):

1. Save each .kml layer as a shapefile by *right-clicking* the layer and choosing the `Save As...` option. Make sure to select `ESRI Shapefile` as *Format* and the relevant CRS.
2. Load all three of your route shapefiles then run the **Merge vector layers** tool from either the *menubar*:

   ```
   Vector > Data Management Tools > Merge vector layers
   ```

   or from the *Processing Toolbox*:

   ```
   Processing Toolbox > QGIS geoalgorithms > Vector general tools > Merge vector layers
   ```

   The output should be a single linestring shapefile containing your routes.